# Rellenar los datos con Selenium y scrapear datos devueltos

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scraping

Estoy intentando rellenar un formulario con selenium en python, al rellenar el formulario en la misma página se devuelve los resultados en forma de tabla, de esa tabla yo quiero extraer todos los rows y ya por último extraerlo en un archivo de texto.
El código me funciona hasta el scraping de la tabla con los resultados.

url --> https://incentivos.agenciaandaluzadelaenergia.es/Orden2016SIG/listado.jsp

Del forrmulario son dos campos a rellenar "LINEA" y "PROVINCIA" y luego darle a filtrar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego te genera la tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí es ya donde tengo el problema y no puedo scrapear los rows resultantes.

Dejo aquí el código:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from time import sleep

# URL Objetivo

webpage = r"https://incentivos.agenciaandaluzadelaenergia.es/Orden2016SIG/listado.jsp"

# Parámetros formulario

linea = "PYME SOSTENIBLE"
provincia = "CÓRDOBA"

# Apertura del navegador
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedgedriver.exe')
driver.get(webpage)

# Introduccion del parametro LINEA en el formulario
sbox = driver.find_element_by_name('LINEA')
sbox.send_keys(linea)
sleep(5)
# Introduccion del parametro PROVINCIA en el formulario
ciudad = driver.find_element_by_name('PROV')
ciudad.send_keys(provincia)
sleep(5)
# Pulsacion del botón FILTRAR
submit = driver.find_element_by_id('filt')
submit.click()

sleep(5)
# Scrap de los resultados. Aqui el problema
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

bs = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')

tr = bs.find_all('tr')
for t in tr:
    print(t.get_text())
```

El error que me muestra en el VSCode es el siguiente a la hora de cuando el programa intenta scrapear

```
C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:417: MarkupResemblesLocatorWarning: "https://incentivos.agenciaandaluzadelaenergia.es/Orden2016SIG/listado.jsp" looks like a URL. Beautiful Soup is not an HTTP client. You should probably use an HTTP client like requests to get the document behind the URL, and feed that document to Beautiful Soup.
  warnings.warn(
```

Gracias.

Comment: Hola, no soy un experto en esto pero al buscar tu error aparece [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768858/beautifulsoup-responses-with-error) respuesta del sitio en ingles. Básicamente dice que estas pasando la URL como string y que antes debes de obtener el contendió de la pagina y después pasarlo.... Puedes utilizar `urllib2` :) ¿donde, cuando, como? no tengo idea... espero te sea ayuda, es lo mejor que puedo hacer por ti.

Comment: Está resulta, lo que he hecho ha sido usar PhantomJS lo que me permitió guardar el codigo en un archivivo y en ese archivo le hice el scrapping

Comment: Chido, podrias poner tu solucion como respuesta a la pregunta y aceptarla por si alguien se encuentra en tu missma situacion en un futuro.